# How to add a static link among pdoMenu/Wayfinder items?

Tags: modx-revolution

I have a dyn menu, generated by one of mentioned plugins. I want to add a static anchor to the same page section among dyn generated menu items.

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what you mean by dyn, but you could make a Weblink Resource Type and give that the `#anchor-name` instead of a URL. This would allow that Resource to behave like any other Resource in the menu but on clicking it would fire whatever you put in the URL field. https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/weblink

Comment: That means "dynamically". Provide your info as answer, please, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a Weblink Resource Type and give that the `#anchor-name` instead of a URL. In terms of displaying in the menu, this would allow that Resource to behave like any other Resource menu link, but on clicking it would fire whatever you put in the URL field.

Documentation here: https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/weblink